# How do I calculate heat and work done by a mixing process in an isolated system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

If I have an ideally insulated container with two segments separated by a partition, each filled with with the same fluid but under different conditions, how can I predict the properties of the combined fluid when the partition is removed? Suppose one compartment is 3kg of liquid water at 200°C and 40 bar, and the other compartment is 1kg of water vapor also at 200°C but only at 1 bar. For each separate compartment I can find their intrinsic properties because I have temperature and pressure, but what about after they are mixed? I know the system as a whole will contain the same amount of energy, but how do I know what shape the energy takes? If the liquid ends up expanding into a vapor, won’t this  require work to perform? The two compartments likely didn’t have the same internal energy, so will heat be transferred in the process? I would imagine that since both compartments are at the same temperature the system will settle at 200°C, but does that imply that there is no heat transfer in the process?

Answer (score 1):

At equilibrium, we know that the total energy will be the same as it was originally (First Law) and that the total entropy will be maximized (Second Law). It's a standard thermodynamics exercise to show that the temperature, pressure, chemical potential, and any other [intensive properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties) are therefore uniform at equilibrium, presuming that the corresponding extensive properties are free to shift (e.g., that net evaporation is free to occur if the gas phase isn't saturated).

Heat and work may occur, but since these are path-dependent variables and since abruptly removing the partition makes the exact path a mystery (who can measure accurate parameters during a sudden and nonuniform change?), we don't know how much of each contributed to the energy exchange between the regions.

As an example, even though both regions started at the same temperature, we don't know if some heat transfer was driven by cooling from compressive heating or expansion cooling as the pressures equalized. Maybe some, maybe a lot.

If we constrained the path (e.g., by allowing the partition to move quasistatically to equilibrate the pressure, removing the partition, and then dissipating the work collected from the movement as heat), then we could calculate the individual contributions of heat and work. For instance, the work could be calculated by integrating $-P\,dV$, where the pressure $P$ and $V$ of each region is known at all times because the movement is quasistatic.

Answer (score 1):

Because this combination of two chambers of water is rigid and insulated, the change in internal energy of the system will be zero.  The mass of water is also constant and the combined volume is constant.  You can calculate the internal energy and volume of the contents of each chamber initially.  The first chamber is pure liquid water and the second chamber is superheated vapor.  All you need is a set of steam tables.  You can then again use the steam tables to satisfy the final constraints of total internal energy, total mass, and total volume.  Most likely, you will have a saturated mixture of liquid and vapor at final steady state.